# WCF REST Service with Java.IO.InputStream as body input

Tags: java, wcf, rest, inputstream

So i am developing some WCF REST WebService methods. The application that will consume them is a blackbox to me, i only know it is a Phonegap app (java) and the method definition. I also have the sourcecode for the equivalent JAVA rest services developed for the same app, but for a different system. The idea is that many HR systems can use the same app by implementing the webservices.

The documentation says method expects **"application/json"**  in the body of the request, which translates to regular String in .NET. Howeber I get a bad request when i deploy the webservice and have the Phonegap-App call this method.

Seeing the already-implemented and working properly java implemenation of the service, the said method expects a **Java.Io.InputStream** as input in the body like that :

```
@Override
public Response manageSubAbs(String codeEnv, String user, String password, String produit, String module, InputStream absSubFlux) 
{
//do stuff
}
```

All parameters but the last one are URL-Query parameters, the Inputstream is expected in the body as i confirmed via Fiddler. So, since there is no InputStream equivalent in .NET ....is there a way i can develop a WCF REST method accepts such an input or what are my options?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, in .NET, try like that:

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "MobileUploadPhoto?JobId={jobId}&SessionId={sessionId}&Description={description}&DateTaken={dateTaken}&TypeId={typeid}", Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        public string MobileUploadPhoto (String jobId, String sessionId, String description, string dateTaken, int typeid, Stream image)
```

Or download

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "MobileDownloadPhotoThumbnailByFileId?SessionId={sessionId}&FileId={fileId}&JobId={jobId}",  BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        public Stream MobileDownloadPhotoThumbnailByFileId(string sessionId, int fileId, int jobId)
```

I hope I understood correctly your question.

Comment: Yes you do understand correct and i did try to use "System.IO.Stream" to represent the "Java.IO.InputStream" variable that will be coming in the body of the request but i got a "405:Method not allowed" so i assume  System.IO.Stream is not the way to go. Have you ever consumed a .NET web service from a java app that passes Java.IO.Inputstream?

Comment: There is no difference between calling the .net wcf services from java if you are using JSON. 

Please check if you are calling the service as:
site.com/Service.svc/MethodName

Normally, if you try in browser to check this, you'll obtain Method not allowed message.